# Detect verb used to open a file in my application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a extension associated with my application, and it opens it fine, but I also want to detect what verb is being used as I intend to have my application handle Open and Edit differently. How can I detect the invoked verb in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your app for verbs and then check the argument in your `Main(string[] args)` method.

This is the modified example of registry keys from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   MyProgram.exe
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = C:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /open "%1"
         print
            command
               (Default) = C:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /print "%1"
         printto
            command
               (Default) = C:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /printto "%1" "%2"
```

So, your `Main` method can look like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length > 0)
            if (args[0] == "/print")
                // do print stuff
            else
                // etc.
        // rest of the program
    }
```

Comment: Those are using command line switches to detect action, not the verb itself.

Comment: @Wobbles Yes, that's right. You can find the verb by checking the switch.

Comment: I know I can check the switch, I'm already doing that as a workaround, But that is checking for the switch not the actual verb directly, I have seen other extensions not have to go through this workaround so it must be possible.